# Advice me with Java WordNet Library

Tags: java, wordnet

I am trying to use JWNL library I am getting error "int cannot be dereferenced". Code is below:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        // TODO add your handling code here:
       try{
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("D:\\jwnl14-rc2\\jwnl14-rc2\\config\\file_properties.xml"));
        Dictionary dict = Dictionary.getInstance();
         System.out.println("Allah Akber");
         IndexWord word=dict.lookupIndexWord(POS.VERB,"run");//  Here is the error int cannot be dereferenced
         Synset[] senses = word.getSenses();
         for (int i = 0; i < senses.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(word + ": " + senses[i].getGloss());
         }
       } catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println("Error during the initialization"+ " "+ex.getMessage());}


}
```

Please advice me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a compilation error.  If it occurred here:

```
     IndexWord word=dict.lookupIndexWord(POS.VERB,"run");
```

then either `dict` or `POS` has a declared type of `int`, and the dereference (i.e. the `.` operator) makes no sense.

Clearly `dict` is declared to have type `Dictionary`.  But `POS` ... ?  I can't see its declaration.  It is not in the code you have shown us.

Comment: I can't tell ... without seeing how `dict` and `POS` are declared.

Comment: How could I know how dict and pos are declared?

Comment: By looking at the declarations ... of course!  You do know what a declaration is don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
import static net.didion.jwnl.data.POS.VERB;

IndexWord word = dict.lookupIndexWord(VERB,"run");
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a note and explain how this will fix the problem?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.